# Speech API RecognizerIntent - Bypass the Didn't catch that. try speaking again message

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have implemented the RecognizerIntent and called google's voice recognition service and it works fine and i get results.  However, sometimes if i mumble or am too far away from my device i get the message "Didn't catch that. Try speaking again." message.  Is there a way to bypass this and not show this message as i don't want the users to have to press OK to continue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) if you want to be in control of the UI.

If I understand correctly then you are launching the `RecognizerIntent` and this gets handled by one of the activities in the Google Search app (or Google Voice Search, or whatever it happens to be called currently). Now, since this is an *activity*, it takes over the UI, i.e. it pops up a dialog box, shows a prompt and a VU meter, etc. In case of an error condition, it could in principle return control to your app by sending one of the error codes e.g. `RESULT_NO_MATCH` (as the documentation suggests), but it chooses not to. Instead it pops up a "try again" message. The only way to return to your activity is by pressing BACK, or hoping that the recognition succeeds.

If you want to control more of the user experience then use [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html). This way your are calling a *service* and then interact with it via callbacks. You will be in full control of the UI. Or almost, e.g. the Google app makes a beep when the recognition starts, and there is no way to turn it off and provide your own beep.

Note that this answer is specific (to a specific version) of Google's voice recognition service which is not part of Android proper. It implements part of the `RecognizerIntent`/`SpeechRecognizer` API but its different versions differ in the API coverage and their exact behavior. So this answer might become wrong in the future.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer a bit?  It's not at all clear from the documentation what you would set in `SpeechRecognizer` to inhibit the message.   See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939535